# Finite derivative of the harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, summation

In Knuth's Concrete Mathematics he represents the famous quicksort algorithm in computer science as a infinite sum then shows that sum can be simplified to being essentially harmonic. I want to explore this sum more by taking a finite derivative of the function but I have not taken any discrete math courses and am struggling with notation.

**My question:**

Suppose, $$f(n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Now suppose we take the generalized finite difference of that function, 
$$\Delta _h^\mu [f](x)=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \mu_k f(x+kh)$$

Have I set this up properly?

I want to explore the finite difference of this series. If I have not set this up correctly, might you point me in the right direction of what I might read to learn how to do this myself. Thank you.

Comment: $f$ is not a function of $n$, or is it?

Comment: It is ... $n$ appears both as a free and a bounded variable ... not a very good idea. Besides this: As the harmonic series does not converge ... $f \equiv \infty$.

Comment: To my understanding $f$ is a function of n, otherwise this problem would not work. But I may be confused.

Comment: Part of my reason of asking this martini is that I wanted to explore this: I know the harmonic series diverge, but if I differentiate it to infinity, does that series converge?

Comment: I made some edits. I don't know if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\approx \ln n+\gamma $$
As a sum is basically a discrete integral, the finite derivative of a sum over the upper bound gives you back the summand $f'(n)\asymp \frac{1}{n}$. More formal treatment of differentiation of discrete sums is found [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5739.pdf).

Anyway, I think you can deal with the finite difference implementation now: the difference between two partial sums for different $n$ shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly what I was looking at doing but I will read the link and report back if it was. Thank you for sharing the link. I will read it all.

Comment: Thanks, I read over the resource and I feel like it does accurately help me out.